# React Ant Calendar remove month, year buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ant-design-pro

Need a help in Ant Calendar

```
    import { Calendar } from 'antd';

function onPanelChange(value, mode) {
  console.log(value, mode);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calendar onPanelChange={onPanelChange} />,
  mountNode);
```

I need remove default MONTH, YEAR buttons and other options.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
const headerRender = () => null;

<Calendar
  headerRender={headerRender}
/>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Plain code answers can almost always be improved by providing some explanation. Consider adding a sentence or two, or a link to the documentation that led you to your solution, for example.

Comment: This works. It returns a null node.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ant-fullcalendar-header{
  display:none;
}
```

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12373

Comment: So, what happens when this project dies and the link is dead? Is this an answer that has a lifetime worthy of more than a comment?

Answer (score 1):

For now, there exist no exact solution. But you can use some trick:

Give a custom class name to the calendar component and add below css code

```
.<customClassName>  .ant-fullcalendar-header .ant-radio-group {
    display: none !important
}
```